# Using WebGPURenderer in A-Frame

Tags: optimization, three.js, aframe, webxr, webgpu

Is there a way to replace the default WebGLRenderer of the aframe scene with a WebGPURenderer, now that the official class is present in the threejs library?

I tried naively repacing the renderer with a new WebGPURenderer but I did not succeed (blank canvas).

Comment: Not yet. THREE WebGPURenderer is under heavy development, has tons of missing functionality and it's far from production ready.